# App crash in sleep mode when run in ios 7.1 and ios 8.0

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios8, voip, pjsip

I am checking logs in xcode while application is in sleep mode. I am working with voip based application. I have done all the formalities regarding voip. I am able to keep app in sleep mode more than 20 mins. But after i disconnected device from system, i have run the app in sleep mode. Within 3-4 mins application gets crash. I have checked in device logs crashes.
It is showing like

> < BKProcessAssertion: 0x1463ab50 > id:xxx-xxx-xx... name: Called by
>   SwyxOTT, from -[application enterIntoBackgroundState] process:
>   < BKNewProcess: 0x14529680; com.aahlaad.SwyxiOSClient; pid: 289 >
>   permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner
>   pid:289 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep

I am using keepalive timeout function. You can see below function.  I am using UDP connection, pjsip 2.2.1.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL handler: ^{

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

                }];
```

Is any one knows regarding this issue please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This crash is a result of calling `-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` without a matching `-endBackgroundTask:`.  At the very least, you should end the background task within the expiration handler, as such:

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskID];
    backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

Sources:

- [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)
- [App Programming Guide for iOS: Executing Finite-Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=YES;
}
```

Comment: This does not fix his crash, nor does it keep his app alive when the screen is off.  All it does is prevent iOS from automatically dimming and eventually turning off the screen. Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled):  `The only apps that should disable the idle timer are mapping apps, games, or programs where the app needs to continue displaying content when user interaction is minimal.`